# Why lazy load if images are not render blocking?

Tags: html, performance

While I am sure there is an obvious answer, a thorough search of Google and SO has not offered me one. If images do not block the render, why lazy load for performance? Is it only to preserve network bandwidth for other items, or as a courtesy to the user to avoid using network or memory unnecessarily?

Comment: The intention is to give bandwidth and prioritise the important render blocking items.

Comment: For the user, if they don't scroll down, they save network by only loading the content visible on screen. And this saves lot of initial page load time.